# Notify the player that another is challenging him

Tags: php, android, sockets, libgdx, server-sent-events

I am developing a simple multiplayer card game for Android.

I'm looking for the simplest (possibly free) solution to immediately alert the player that another is challenging him.

The actual flow:

- Player1 presses a button to challenge player2
- Player2 receives the notification in the game ONLY if he presses the "check new challenges" button

The desired flow:

- Player1 presses a button to challenge player2
- Player2 receives the notification almost immediately: in-game if the game is opened, through notification if the app was closed

My App is made with **Java** and **LibGDX**.

My server is a **Linux** web shared hosting with **PHP 7.0.33**, here I cannot install ratchet, composer, or others, I haven't access to SSH.

Some details in `phpinfo()`:

- 'Configure Command' has `'--enable-sockets=shared'`
- 'Registered Stream Socket Transports' has `tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2`
- 'curl - UNIX_SOCKETS' = `true`
- 'sockets - Sockets Support' = `true'
- 'default_socket_timeout' = `true`

I found these options on the web:

- [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), [firebase REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages?hl=en): Firebase solutions seem complex and time-consuming to set up and study, with a server (I only have shared web hosting) or push notifications requiring me to manually send the notification from the console
- [Schedule repeating alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms): it appears to have a 1 minute limit between two runs and up to two minutes to show the notification, as well as a background run-time limit
- [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest): (a type of [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) ) it has "a minimum interval of 15 minutes"
- **[Server-Sent Events](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)**: I tried it. If both .html and .php files are on localhost it works fine, but instead, if I put the .php file on my hosting I don't receive any messages (even if in the browser console in the network tabs every about 5 seconds a new request appeared).

Please tell me what you advise me to do based on your experience.

**Edit**:

I contacted my web hosting provider: they say that I cannot use WebSockets due to web shared hosting limitations.

So, the only possible way without spend money is through some service/background service or similar directly on Android.

What do you suggest to achieve a less time repeat server HTTP request on Android even if the App is closed?

Comment: If it's a game, the players would like to know instantly the moment someone challenges them, not after some X time. The same principle when a sms is received, after the other user send it. So I suggest using a custom broadcast reciever and web sockets

Comment: @javdromero can you suggest me a url that explain how to do that? I'm using PHP in the backend.

Comment: Depending on your desired framework, there are options like [lavarel broadcast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting) or [with ratchet](https://medium.com/@winni4eva/php-websockets-with-ratchet-5e76bacd7548) i'm sure there are more, those are the ones i've seen

Comment: @javdromero thanks, I see them. I cannot use them, see my edit.

Comment: You say that you can't use composer, but can you clarify more? Composer can just be run directly as a phar if needed, it doesn't need to be "installed". Do you not have SSH access?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, I cannot have SSH access.

Comment: So when they press the check button they can see the challenge.How are you getting the data? I think that's where you can use some sort of refresh timer to keep checking if the data is present

Comment: @KevinGales I get data making a request to server. Making a request every few seconds / minutes is not feasible if the player does not have the game open (Android terminates the process or the background connection is not available after a while)

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach would be a REST API call (firebase is not needed) only a simple web server with PHP + MYSQL does the trick.

I'm more from the PHP / JAVASCRIPT / MYSQL / AJAX world ... :

The AJAX point of view:

• Javascript that periodically or on-demand (div with onclick...) check or "ask" a PHP for some data and return that data in HTML...

in Android I think this tutorial seems interesting :

https://medium.com/@filswino/making-rest-calls-download-upload-files-with-one-line-of-code-on-android-no-retrofit-needed-5c0574f41476

with this lib
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

something like this

```
AndroidNetworking.get("https://www.com/getAllUsers/{pageNumber}")
                 .addPathParameter("pageNumber", "0")
                 .addQueryParameter("limit", "3")
                 .addHeaders("token", "1234")
                 .setTag("test")
                 .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                 .build()
                 .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                      // do anything with response
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                      // handle error
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The problem is how to warn the player as quickly as possible. On mobile devices, resources like connection, RAM, speed, etc. are limited. I should avoid a periodic call in a very short amount of time; if the App uses too many resources in the background (for example when it is closed) it is also considered negatively by Android.

Comment: @user2342558 I'm doing some research and there is a debate for websocket vs ajax vs webrtc.... for multiplayer gaming webrtc is kind of awsome it can provide peer to peer live data exchange (without passing via a server). In Webrtc the server is only there to establish the connection. Once conneceted, data goes from on peer to the other. WebRTC is really hot also for videochat, audiochat, text chat, (any data....) Plus, it's multiplatform desktop+android+ios+etc in a webrtc scenario you could have a player on desktop and the other player in android (it could be within a webview in mobile APP)

Comment: @user2342558 I'm discovering PeerJS https://peerjs.com/examples.html I checked the demo => 1 browser with the send and an other browser with the receive, connect and instant text chat both way (extremely fast)